# Анимация на Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, анимация

Есть приложение на Vue.js :
http://jack-dev.zzz.com.ua

Уже заканчиваю и столкнулся с неожиданным поведением анимации:

анимируется список товаров при добавлении и удалении.
Как сделать, что бы при удалении, когда анимируется scale удаляемого товара, остальные уже ехали на его место, а не потом рывком. Ну как при добавлении сейчас.

И как сделать, что бы товары при переходе по роутам не анимировались. Должна срабатывать анимация роута, прозрачность. Но при этом товары скейлятся и дёргаются (удали несколько товаров войдя в режим админа и переключись на другой роут и назад)

заранее спасибо!

UPDATE:

Ах, да, забыл код приложить. 
В корневом компоненте App.vue view-router, обернутый в transition:

```
`transition(name='fade', mode='out-in', appear='')`
```

scss для него:

```
'
 .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  .fade-enter, .fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0
  }
'
```

В компоненте Store обернуто список товаров обёрнут в transition-group (Pug):

```
    transition-group.row.list__ul(name='storeProd')
      .product.col-sm-6.col-lg-3(
      v-for='(item, index) in items'
      :key='item.id'
      )

     ....
```

Scss для него:

```
  .storeProd-move {
    transition: .5s ease-out;
  }

  .storeProd-active {
    transition: .3s;
  }

  .storeProd-leave-active {
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  .storeProd-enter, .storeProd-leave-to {
    transform: scale(0.0);
  }
```

Вот эта анимации я срабатывает, не должным образом при переключении роута. И не едут товары во время скейла при удалении товара.

Comment: без кода сложно Вам помочь

Comment: Этого не достаточно. Нужен более развернутый

Comment: @Дмытрык - да, забыл код приложить. Я добавил код анимаций в сам вопрос, тут в комментариях почему код не форматировался.

Comment: @Дмытрык не помогло?

Comment: Если я подсказывал Вам как составить вопрос, чтобы иметь шанс получить на него ответ, не означает, что он (ответ) есть у меня.

Comment: Да и под кодом, (в Вашем случае) я имел ввиду, что-то более существенное, чтобы была видна целостная картина, а не  эти обрывки, что Вы предложили. Иногда нужно потратить время, чтобы составить вопрос, достаточный для понимая сути и причин проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо, я учту. Первый раз оформляю вопрос. Но вопрос касательно анимации и весь код который её касается я тут постарался представить. В любом случае спасибо.